# Buttonをクリックしても画面推移しない

Tags: android, java

ボタンをクリックしても画面推移しないことがあります。(することもある)
クリックイベントが設定されている場合はクリックした時に音がなりますが、反応しない時も音はなります。
このコードが原因なのかもしれませんが、何故かわかる方いましたら教えてください。

```
package com.jimdo.solarand.git;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.content.res.*;
/**アプリ起動後に呼び出されるアクティビティ。*/
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public final String thisPkgName="com.jimdo.solarand.git";
    @Override
    /**生成時に呼び出される。*/
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    /**ここでクリックイベントの実装を行っている。クリックイベントでは、それぞれのアクティビティへIntentを使用し推移している*/
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Button pull=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pullbtn);
        Button add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
        Button init=(Button) findViewById(R.id.initbtn);
        Button gitUpdate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.gitupdatebtn);
        Button about=(Button) findViewById(R.id.abouts);
        gitUpdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1){
                    Intent intent =getIntent();
                    intent.setClassName(thisPkgName,"com.jimdo.solarand.git.GitUpdate");

                    startActivity(intent);


                }


        });
        pull.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1){
                    Intent intent=getIntent();
                    intent.setClassName(thisPkgName,"com.jimdo.solarand.git.PullActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
        });
        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1){
                    Intent intent=getIntent();
                    intent.setClassName(thisPkgName,"com.jimdo.solarand.git.CommitActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

        });
        about.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1){
                    Intent i=getIntent();
                    i.setClassName(thisPkgName,"com.jimdo.solarand.git.About");
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        init.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1){
                    Intent i=new Intent();
                    i.setClassName(thisPkgName,"com.jimdo.solarand.git.InitActivity");
                    startActivity(i);
                }

        });
    }
}
```

因みに、Buildし直したら反応するようになります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クリーンビルドをしても何度も発生したので色々変えたところ、IDEが原因です。
この質問を尋ねさせて頂いたときに使っていたIDEはAIDEです。そのAIDEを使わず、Android Studioを使うと反応するようになりました。

Answer (score 0):

実際に似たコードを作成し何度か実行してみましたが、問題を確認できませんでした。
問題はこのコードには無いように思います。

一度クリーンビルドをした上で再度試してみてください。

Comment: 分かりました。クリーンビルドをして実行してみます。

Comment: 遅れましたが出来ました。ありがとうございました。